# How to change google sheet y-axis range

Tags: google-sheets, graph, pivot-table

I am using Google sheet to plot a line graph using a pivot table. but I want that the highest value of y axis will be 10000 more than the highest value of the entries. Like if the highest point is 50000 then the y-axis has range will be 60000. but in my Google sheet, the highest range automatically sets to 100,000. Can anyone please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the settings of the Vertical Axis via the [Chart Editor](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cdelete-or-move-items-on-your-chart%2Cmove-a-chart):

[image: Editor]